# Expectation for the number of comparisons in a randomized Quicksort

Tags: proof-techniques, quicksort

I found this link: http://theory.stanford.edu/~tim/w11/l/qsort.pdf and it kind of theoretically describes how to approach finding  expectation for the number of comparisons in a Quicksort.

Using this, how would I find and prove the expectation for an array of a concrete number of items, for example 5? (see the formula in the second section of the link)
Would my expectation be !https://i.stack.imgur.com/H455V.png)! but replace the n by 5 for example (to get the expected number of comparisons for a 5 length array)

the second formula reads: 
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5tb2.png)!

I understand I should just replcae the n with for example 5 if I want to find the number of comparisons expected for a concrete array, however I don't think I  quite understand how the proof would apply in this case, however. I was wondering if anyone knew an easier proof for finding the expected number of comparisons in a randomized quicksort for an array of length n.

Comment: You should consider clarifying the body of your question(with the help of the link you've added). It is unclearly exactly what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: @LastIronStar done

Comment: Did you try writing down the series term-wise for $\mathbb{E}[C]$ using $n=5$(first part of second formula)?

Comment: I am not really sure how this formula was actually derived in the first place, which is why I don't feel comfortable using it.